# Query vs Transaction

Tags: cqrs, saga

In this picture, we can see saga is the one that implements transactions and cqrs implements queries. As far as I know, a transaction is a set of queries that follow ACID properties.
So can I consider CQRS as an advanced version of saga which increases the speed of reads?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that this diagram is not meant to explain what Sagas and CQRS are. In fact, looking at it this way it is quite confusing. What this diagram is telling you is what patterns you can use to read and write data that spans multime microservices. It is saying that in order to write data (somehow transactionally) across multiple microservices you can use Sagas and in order to read data which belongs to multiple microservices you can use CQRS. But that doesn't mean that Sagas and CQRS have anything in common. They are two different patterns to solve completely different problems (reads and writes). To make an analogy, it's like saying that to make pizzas (Write) you can use an oven and to view the pizzas menu (Read) you can use a tablet.

On the specific patterns:

1. Sagas: you can see them as a process manager or state machine. Note that they do not implement transactions in the RDBMS sense. Basically, they allow you to create a process that will take care of telling each microservice to do a write operation and if one of the operations fails, it'll take care of telling the other microservices to rollback (or compensate) the action that they did. So, these "transactions" won't be atomic, because while the process is running some microservices will have already modified the data and others won't. And it is not garanteed that whatever has succeed can sucessfully be rolled back or compensated.
2. CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation): suggests the separation of Commands (writes) and Queries (Reads). The reason for that, it is what I was saying before, that the reads and writes are two very different operations. Therefore, by separating them, you can implement them with the patterns that better fit each scenario. The reason why CQRS is shown in your diagram as a solution for reading data that comes from multiple microservices is because one way of implementing queries is to listen to Domain Events coming from multiple microservices and storing the information in a single database so that when it's time to query the data, you can find it all in a single place. An alternative to this would be Data Composition. Which would mean that when the query arrives, you would submit queries to multiple microservices at that moment and compose the response with the composition of the responses.

> So can I consider CQRS as an advanced version of saga which increases the speed of reads?

Personally I would not mix the concepts of CQRS and Sagas. I think this can really confuse you. Consider both patterns as two completely different things and try to understand them both independently.